# Whats the best way to do throbber in C#?

Tags: c#, treeview

Specifically what I am looking to do is make the icons for the Nodes in my System.Windows.Forms.TreeView control to throb while a long loading operation is taking place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you load each frame into an ImageList, you can use a loop to update to each frame. 
Example:

> ```
>     bool runThrobber = true;
>     private void AnimateThrobber(TreeNode animatedNode)
>     {
>         BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
>         bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate
>         {
>             while (runThrobber)
>             {
>                 this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
>                 {
>                     animatedNode.SelectedImageIndex++;
>                     if (animatedNode.SelectedImageIndex >= imageList1.Images.Count) > animatedNode.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
>                 });
>                 Thread.Sleep(100);
>             }
>         });
>         bg.RunWorkerAsync();
>     }
> ```

Obviously there's more than a few ways to implement this, but here's the basic idea.

Comment: Looking at this again, you should really check and see if the image index is in the bounds of the imagelist.images count before you increment it.